# Memory leak with ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

i have memory leak when using `ConcurrentQueue` :

```
requestObject request = xxx;

Item obj= new Item ();
obj.MessageReceived += obj_MessageReceived;
obj.Exited += obj_Exited;

request.Key = obj.Key;

obj.AddRequest(request);

_queue.TryAdd(obj.Key, obj);
```

In the "Exited" callback, i dispose the resource :

```
void LiveSphere_Exited(string key)
{
    Item instance;

    _queue.TryRemove(key, out instance);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var wait = new SpinWait();
        while (instance.MessageCount > 0)
        {
            wait.SpinOnce();
        }
    })
    .ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
         if (instance != null)
         {
             //Cleanup resources
             instance.MessageReceived -= obj_MessageReceived;
             instance.Exited -= obj_Exited;
             instance.Dispose();
             instance = null;
         }
    });
}
```

When I profile the code, i still have a root referenced "Item" object but I don't know where I can dispose...,
The exited method is triggered and the _queue has removed the "Item" object from the queue.

When I read documentation, the concurrentqueue copy the reference into the queue.

Can you help me to find out where the memory leak is?

Comment: Not sure where your memory leak is. There was a memory leak in the .NET 4.0 version of `ConcurrentQueue`, but it's been fixed for 4.5. You might consider looking into `BlockingCollection`, which is a much nicer wrapper around concurrent collections. The default behavior used `ConcurrentQueue` internally.

Comment: I'd hesitate to call .NET 4's `ConcurrentQueue` leaky -- mainly this only happened if you were not using it much (it would not set the data to `null` until several items had been popped) -- in which case, what's the point of a `ConcurrentQueue`?

Comment: Thank you Jim but i'm already in .NET 4.5 and i need FIFO queue, does the blocking collection is FIFO?

Comment: @dnx: `BlockingCollection` is a wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue`. So, yes, it is FIFO.

Comment: If it fits your need you could create a synchronized wrapper for a standard queue using Queue.Synchronized(normalQueue).

Comment: @gsscoder Using a blocking collection will perform better (it only synchronizes when it needs to, rather than always, and even avoid it in a lot of situations you might not think it could) and has more operations that appear atomic externally.

Comment: @corynelson: not true, using 4.5 version and debugged into same leak ConcurrentQueue<T>+Segment<X>

Answer (score 6):

Unlike a standard .NET Queue, calling Dequeue() does not remove the reference to the object from the collection.  While this behavior has changed from the 4.0 version to the 4.5 version (I have read this, but have not tested it) it is not a bug, but a conscious design decision made by the framework team as a part of designing a thread-safe, enumerable collection.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/05/08/concurrentqueue-lt-t-gt-holding-on-to-a-few-dequeued-elements.aspx) has more information, including a workaround by using StrongBox to wrap the objects that go into the ConcurrentQueue.  That should be a suitable work-around until you can move to the 4.5 framework.

Comment: I'd call it "a conscious design bug", considering its outcome.

Comment: I have tried this StrongBox approach but only delays the issue. memory still increases to about 1.7GIG, then the app has delay issues and crashes.

Comment: Here's an updated [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/concurrentqueuet-holding-on-to-a-few-dequeued-elements/) to the mentioned article, written by Stephen Toub.

Answer (score 5):

I have looked implementation of the Concurrent Queue. There are cases when the queue will hold references to the object after Dequeue() was called.

Concurrent Queue uses Segments to store data. There it is a part of the TryRemove method of the segment:

```
// If there is no other thread taking snapshot (GetEnumerator(), ToList(), etc), reset the deleted entry to null.
// It is ok if after this conditional check m_numSnapshotTakers becomes > 0, because new snapshots won't include 
// the deleted entry at m_array[lowLocal]. 
if (m_source.m_numSnapshotTakers <= 0)
{
    m_array[lowLocal] = default(T); //release the reference to the object. 
}
```

So when you have a different thread that enumerates the queue at the same time you dequeue an object references to the object will not be set to null.