# Memory Leak in ConcurrentQueue<T>?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a simple class in a .NET Core SDK -> 3.1.409 project for the communication with devices.

```
public class WriteCommand
{
    //Commands is an enumeration. 
    public Commands LaserCommand { get; }

    public List<byte> Parameter { get; }

    public List<byte> Data { get; }

    public WriteCommand(Commands laserCommand, byte[] parameter = null)
    {
        Data = BuildSendData(laserCommand, parameter);
        Parameter = new List<byte>(parameter);
        LaserCommand = laserCommand;
    }

    private List<byte> BuildSendData(Commands command, byte[] paramBytes)
    {
        var parameter = paramBytes ?? Array.Empty<byte>();
        int numberOfBytes = parameter.Length + Constants.ADD_TO_PARAMETER; // Defined by protocol        

        List<byte> sendData = new List<byte>();

        sendData.Add(Constants.PACKET_START_BYTE);

        sendData.Add((byte)numberOfBytes);

        sendData.Add(Constants.COMMAND_START_BYTE);

        sendData.Add((byte)command);

        foreach (var param in parameter)
        {
            sendData.Add(param);
        }

        sendData.Add(Constants.PACKET_END_BYTE);

        byte checksum = new CheckSumCalculator().CalculateCheckSum(sendData);
        sendData.Add(checksum);

        return sendData;
    }
}
```

I use this class to add to a ConcurrentQueue in one taks like this.

```
    public void AddCommand()
    {
        commandsQueue.Enqueue(new WriteCommand(Commands.SetRs232BaudRate));
    }
```

And in another task I get the command out of the ConcurrentQueue

```
    public void SendAndReceiveMessages()
    {
        while (!commandsQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            if (commandsQueue.TryDequeue(out WriteCommand writeCommand))
            {
               //Do something                    
            }
        }
    }
```

In my progam I habe 6 devices to communicate within an interval of one second. Each device has it's own communication class.

When the program run for a while (more than 2 days) I see an increase of the needed memory.

I Check this with the a memory profiler and see a memory leak:

- WriteCommand
- ConcurrentQueueSegment+Slot

This is only [articel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041373/memory-leak-with-concurrentqueue)I found.

You can find the example code [here](https://github.com/MichaelInsberg/Example)

Does anyone know this problem?

Greetings Mike

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: as your link suggest, its tied to .net implementation which may vary between versions. mind telling us your .net version?

Comment: After removing from queue, when are you disposing your `command` objects!? Did you consider making the Writecommand class implement the `IDisposable` interface

Comment: Where is the need to dispose the Command class. There is nothing to dispose inside the class.

Comment: Why do you think is a memory leak? Try forcing Garbage collector with GC.Collect. BTW, you might want to use Task.Run instead, and not using Thread.Sleep inside your Tasks, async await Task.Delay is preferable.